# How can I automatically give another role to a user once they receive a specific role?

Tags: discord-jda

I want the user to receive a role called "ADMINISTRATOR" when he gets the "OWNER" role and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to detect when a role is given to a member, you have to setup a listener listening to the `GuildMemberRoleAddEvent`.
Whenever a role is added to a member you just have to check, if it's either the "ADMINISTRATOR" or the "OWNER" role. If this is the case you can add the missing role to the member.

Be aware, that the member might already have the role. In this case you won't need to add it.

This is how such a class could look like:

```java
public class GuildMemberRoleAddListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberRoleAdd(GuildMemberRoleAddEvent event) {
        if (event.getRoles().contains(event.getGuild().getRolesByName("OWNER", true).get(0)) && !event.getMember().getRoles().contains(event.getGuild().getRolesByName("ADMINISTRATOR", true).get(0))) {
            event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(event.getMember(), event.getGuild().getRolesByName("ADMINISTRATOR", true).get(0)).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

It's up to you to write the rest of the code and to implement this feature by yourself.

With some slight changes you could turn it into a command as well, in case some members already have one of the roles, in which case the event wouldn't trigger.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how should I check if the user has the "OWNER" role?

Comment: updated my answer, it's basically event.getRoles().contains(event.getGuild().getRolesByName("OWNER", true).get(0))

Comment: It works, thank you

Comment: It is convention to use UpperCamelCase for class names and adding the `@Override` annotation can save you from a lot of trouble